# Fractional solutions

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, linear-programming

Suppose I have a complete bipartite graph $(V_1,V_2, E)$. I am studying the problem

$$\max \sum_{v_1} \sum_{v_2} x_{v_1, v_2} $$
subject to
$$\sum_{v_2} x_{v_1, v_2} \leq E_{v_1}, \forall v_1 \in V_1$$
and
$$\sum_{v_1} x_{v_1,v_2}c_{v_1,v_2} \leq E_{v_2}, \forall v_2 \in V_2$$
$$x \geq 0 $$
where $E_{v_1}$ and $E_{v_2}$ are positive integers for all $v_1$ and $v_2$ and $c \geq 0$. I know that a basic feasible solution has at most $|V_1| + |V_2|$ elements being non-zero. Fix any BFS $x$. Is there a way to bound the number fractional elements of these solutions as a function of $V_2$? Namely,
$$ |\text{# of fractional } x_{v_1,v_2}| \leq f(\{E_{v_2}\}_{v_2 \in V_2},V_2)$$
for some function $f$?

Comment: Where are $E_1$ and $E_2$ use in the question?

Comment: @VezenBU Just positive integers. The function $f$ may depend of of $E_1$ and $E_2$. For what I have read, this is sort-of-a generalized assortment problem.

Comment: @thewatcher I think you misunderstood the question - the problem is that the positive integers $E_1$ and $E_2$, which you mention after the statement of the problem, never appear in its objective function or constraints. Do you just mean that for every $v \in V_1 \cup V_2$, $E_v$ is a positive integer? Or do you additionally mean that for all $v_1 \in V_1$, $E_{v_1}$ is the same value $E_1$, and for all $v_2 \in V_2$, $E_{v_2}$ is the same value $E_2$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for the clarification, I edited my post. $E_{v_i}$ is a positive integer, that can be different of any other $E_{v_j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can indeed prove an upper bound of $2|V_2|$ on the number of fractional variables in a basic solution. (Let's assume that $|V_1| > |V_2|$, otherwise this bound is trivial.)

A basic solution is specified by selecting a basic variable for each constraint. I will write $x(v)$ (with $v \in V_1 \cup V_2$) for the basic variable corresponding to $v$'s constraint. This variable $x(v)$ is either one of the variables $x_{v_1, v_2}$ with $v \in \{v_1, v_2\}$, or it is a slack variable only appearing in $v$'s constraint.

The very lazy upper bound on the number of fractional variables is $|V_1| + |V_2|$, just because only the variables $x(v)$ with $v \in V_1 \cup V_2$ can be fractional - all other variables are $0$. We can do better by dividing the basic variables into three classes:

1. The basic variables $x(v_2)$ with $v_2 \in V_2$.
2. The basic variables $x(v_1)$ with $v_1 \in V_1$, such that there exists *some* $v_2 \in V_2$ for which $x(v_2) = x_{v_1, v_2}$.
3. All other basic variables $x(v_1)$ with $v_1 \in V_1$.

There are exactly $|V_2|$ basic variables in the first class - fewer, if we do not count the ones that are slack variables.

There are also at most $|V_2|$ basic variables in the second class - at most one for each basic variable in the first class.

So we get an upper bound of $2|V_2|$ fractional variables by showing that every basic variable $x(v_1)$ in the *third* class must be an integer. Well, $v_1$'s constraint (with a slack variable $s_{v_1}$ included) is
$$
   \sum_{v_2 \in V_2} x_{v_1, v_2} + s_{v_1} = E_{v_1}.
$$
If $x(v_1)$ is in the third class, none of the variables $x_{v_1, v_2}$ are $x(v_2)$ - so none of them are basic for any constraint except *possibly* this one. So when we set all the nonbasic variables to $0$, this constraint becomes $x(v_1) = E_{v_1}$. Therefore $x(v_1)$ is an integer.

Comment: Can you explain "Up to $|V_2|$ of these variables are basic for a constraint from the second set"? Mainly how to identify a basic variable of the second set. Also, if a constraint of the first set contains one of the latter basic variables, doesn't that mean that there are most |V_2| variables in each constraint, yielding a bound of $|V_2|^2$ fractional variables in total?

Comment: For each constraint, there is exactly one basic variable. Which one - that's specified by the specific basic feasible solution we've got.

Comment: I've added some notation for talking about these basic variables which will hopefully make my argument more clear.

Comment: I guess the part I do not understand is: "A basic solution is specified by selecting a basic variable for each constraint". For what I understand, a basic solution is selected (in the system $Ax=b$) by considering $|V_1| + |V_2|$ columns of the matrix, so I do not see the direct relation between selecting a column and selecting a variable (because multiple variables can appear in one column).

Comment: What do you mean "multiple variables can appear in one column"? Columns directly correspond to variables. In a system $Ax = b$, the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of $A$ gives the coefficients of the $i^{\text{th}}$ component of $x$. A basic solution is selected by choosing $|V_1| + |V_2|$ *linearly independent* columns of the matrix $A$, then multiplying by the inverse of those columns to solve for the variables those columns correspond to. Those variables are the basic variables, and the other variables are nonbasic (and set to $0$ in the basic solution).

Comment: That's the overview - if you have remaining questions, I think they might be more fundamental than the specific problem here.